# How would the DI container use the a Func<> delegate type in the services.AddTransient() method?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1, c#-9.0

I am trying to leverage some source code up in GitHub for some integrations services.  I saw the following code in the *Startup.cs* files `ConfigurationServices()`.

The line that is in the method is:

```
services.AddTransient<Func<DbConnection, IIntegrationEventLogService>>(sp => 
    (DbConnection c) => new IntegrationEventLogService(c)
);
```

I understand what Func/Delegates are.  My question is how and and when does the container instantiate this instance and pass it in?

I am trying to go through the rest of the code sample and identify how it is used and I cant see anything.

Comment: its a factory method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addtransient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddTransient__2_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider___1__

Comment: @DanielA.White What is a factory method?  i dont understand what is on that link.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: As a transient life cycle, an object instance needs to be created every time a dependency is injected. By default, the dependency injection container will attempt to instantiate a new instance based on either the _empty_ or _default_ constructor—or by mapping parameters to dependencies. The delegate offers you more control over that process by supplying a factory method. The factory method is executed when it needs to instantiate the new object instance, thus giving you custom control over _how_ it is initialized.

Comment: If the _Func_ was registered as singleton (AddSingleton), would we only get one _IntegrationEventLogService_ instance? Or just the Func placeholder/reference that's reused? Thanks.